# Does sudo make things faster?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python program that takes a while to execute and I want to know does doing this make it faster:

```
sudo python test.py
```

Or is it as fast as this:

```
python test.py
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suspect people will answer "try it and see which one is faster".

Comment: Depends on the contents of test.  If it's filled with `try/except` on file permission errors with different routes, yes, running it as root could make it faster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because empirical testing answers the question

Comment: I think it is conceivable that running a python task with `sudo` could change execution time in some situations, perhaps as a side-effect of running with different permissions. While the question may be answerable empirically for a given application in a given environment, it's not a priori obvious that there aren't some situations that would cause a python application to run faster/slower with sudo or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously said, `sudo` has nothing to do with speed execution (except for very marginal situations). On the other hand, you may be interested by using `nice` (type `man nice`) but if you really care about speed, you should rather consider using another language (like C, Fortran or Julia), care about a better algorithm, etc.

If you can, try also to run your code with `pypy` instead of the usual version of Python; it is another interpreter which is often quicker (but you may encounter issues if you use many non standard libraries). See: http://pypy.org/

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` has nothing to do with execution time, rather it deals with execution right.

If you want to execute a python file as  `root` user, you will use `sudo`. Not only executing python files, use `sudo` if you need to gain `root` access.

Comment: nicely explained.